# 18.04 requires 2nd boot

Tags: xubuntu

I recently allowed software updater to update xubuntu 18.04. Upon booting the system freezes with blank screen and requires crashing the machine. The next boot presents the grub menu and boots normally. This happens every time I boot now. I'm not Linux experienced so I need detailed instructions.

Comment: Do you know how to fsck your Ubuntu disk partition?

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

To check your Ubuntu file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`